# Find multiple regex in an array

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an an array containing various timeslots :

```
var timeArray = ["00:05 - 02:50", "03:05 - 05:50", "05:10 - 07:55", "06:25 - 09:10", "07:55 - 10:40", "09:00 - 11:45", "15:10 - 17:55", "17:05 - 19:45", "18:50 - 21:35", "19:40 - 22:25", "20:45 - 23:40", "22:00 - 00:45", "22:40 - 01:25", "11:55 - 16:15"]
```

I want to search all the timeslots between 06-12 and push them in an array. I wrote below js but this is returning me an empty array:

```
var resultArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < timeArray.length; i++) {
    var bar = /^06:^07:^08:^09:^10:^11/;
    if (bar.test(timeArray[i])) {
        alert("found desired timeslots");
        resultArray.push(timeArray[i]);
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you mean to match the first two digits? `/^(?:0[6-9]|1[01])/`?

Comment: Basically I need to fix the regex variable

Comment: Change the `:` to a `|`

Comment: FWIW, `^06:^07:^08:^09:^10:^11` matches a string starting with "06:^07:^08:^09:^10:^11" (like literally); regular expressions follow rules, [use a guide/reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) and [follow guided practice](https://regexone.com/) to increase productivity - because there an infinite set of invalid patterns :}

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew that worked . Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression should rather be: `^06|^07|^08|^09|^10|^11`. Another more concise alternative would be: `/^0[6-9]|^1[01]/`

Runnable example below:

```js
var timeArray = ["00:05 - 02:50", "03:05 - 05:50", "05:10 - 07:55", "06:25 - 09:10", "07:55 - 10:40", "09:00 - 11:45", "15:10 - 17:55", "17:05 - 19:45", "18:50 - 21:35", "19:40 - 22:25", "20:45 - 23:40", "22:00 - 00:45", "22:40 - 01:25", "11:55 - 16:15"]

var resultArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < timeArray.length; i++) {
  var bar = /^06|^07|^08|^09|^10|^11/;
  if (bar.test(timeArray[i])) {
    console.log("found desired timeslots: " + timeArray[i]);
    resultArray.push(timeArray[i]);
  }
};
```

Comment: If you repeat the start of string anchor, you do not need a grouping construct here. `var bar = /^06|^07|^08|^09|^10|^11/;` will do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, you are right. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could takes some groups for the wanted times and use only one start indicator.

```js
var timeArray = ["00:05 - 02:50", "03:05 - 05:50", "05:10 - 07:55", "06:25 - 09:10", "07:55 - 10:40", "09:00 - 11:45", "15:10 - 17:55", "17:05 - 19:45", "18:50 - 21:35", "19:40 - 22:25", "20:45 - 23:40", "22:00 - 00:45", "22:40 - 01:25", "11:55 - 16:15"],
    resultArray = timeArray.filter(s => /^(0[6-9]|1(0|1))/.test(s));

console.log(resultArray);
```